# Node.js project deployment without internet

Tags: node.js, deployment, executable

What is the best way to deploy Node.js project to the machine without access to the internet? For example in a private network? Is there any option to make one package containing all of dependencies for the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. in order to deploy a project, you don't need to download anything from the internet- you need it only for running `npm install` when building the project. if all dependencies are already there, you can just run it.
2. if you need it also for building the project, you can create a local npm repository and put in there all relevant dependencies

Comment: #1 is *mostly* true - you will run into problems if you have node packages that compile native code and the dev & target systems have different architectures. I've run into problems when moving from Ubuntu to Alpine Linux; it goes without saying that moving from Intel to ARM systems will also result in problems.

Comment: What do you mean by creating local npm repository? Can I somehow point npm to use local storage?

Comment: Okay, I googled for creating local npm repos and here's the solution:
http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository